# Android - Retrieve Contact Photo and Display

Tags: android, photo, android-contacts, contacts

I am creating a simple application that retrieves the name and phone number of each individual contact and display in a list view along with the contact's photo in a thumbnail sized image-view at the beginning of the row.

I have managed to retrieve and display the name and number but have failed at getting the photo to display after going through many tutorials and stacks.

I eventually rolled it back to just displaying the name and number.

Can anyone help with the contact photo, I have provided my code below.

Thanks in advance!

---Contact getters and setters---
This method gets the name and number correctly but i am not sure if im getting the photo correctly.

```
 package content;

 import android.net.Uri;


 public class ContactBean {
private String name;
private String phoneNo;
private Uri proPic;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}
public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}

public Uri getPhotoUri() {
    return this.proPic;
}

public void setPhotoUri(Uri photoUri) {
    this.proPic = proPic;
}

}
```

---BackUpListActivity---

```
package backUpContacts;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import backUpContacts.BackUpListActivity;

import com.example.contactflipper.R;

import content.ContactBean;


 import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class BackUpListActivity extends Activity implements
OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
private String contactID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.save_backups);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    String image_uri = "";
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  null,
            null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {

        String name = phones
                .getString(phones
                         .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


        ContactBean objContact = new ContactBean();
        objContact.setName(name);
        objContact.setPhoneNo(phoneNumber);
        list.add(objContact);

    }
    phones.close();

    BackUpListAdapter objAdapter = new BackUpListAdapter(
            BackUpListActivity.this, R.layout.save_list_row, list);
    listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

    if (null != list && list.size() != 0) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ContactBean>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(ContactBean lhs, ContactBean rhs) {
                return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                BackUpListActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("");

        alert.setMessage(list.size() + " Contact Found!!!");

        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();

    } else {
        showToast("No Contact Found!!!");
    }
}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    ContactBean bean = (ContactBean) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
    //implement something on the click of each listed item - bean
}

}
```

---BackUpListAdapter---

```
package backUpContacts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import viewContacts.GridAdapter.ViewHolder;

import com.example.contactflipper.R;

 import content.ContactBean;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BackUpListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactBean> implements  OnClickListener{

private Activity activity;
private List<ContactBean> items;
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
private int row;
private ContactBean objBean;

public BackUpListAdapter(Activity act, int row, List<ContactBean> items) {
    super(act, row, items);

    this.activity = act;
    this.row = row;
    this.items = items;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        itemChecked.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
    }

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);

    holder.tvname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
    holder.tvPhoneNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvphone);
    holder.ivPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

    if (holder.tvname != null && null != objBean.getName()
            && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvname.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
    }
    if (holder.tvPhoneNo != null && null != objBean.getPhoneNo()
            && objBean.getPhoneNo().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvPhoneNo.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getPhoneNo()));
    }


    final CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkMarkContact); // your
    // CheckBox
    cBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkMarkContact);

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                itemChecked.set(position, true);
                // do some operations here
            } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                itemChecked.set(position, false);
                // do some operations here
            }
        }
    });
    cBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
    // CheckBox in ListView
    // according to their original
    // position and CheckBox never
    // loss his State when you
    // Scroll the List Items.



    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvname, tvPhoneNo;
    public ImageView ivPic;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

In the above code i believe i need something similar to this

```
if (holder.tvPhoneNo != null && null != objBean.getPhoneNo()
            && objBean.getPhoneNo().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvPhoneNo.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getPhoneNo()));
    }
```

except for the photos to be displayed.

I also have already created an imageview in the xml and declared it in the above code

```
  holder.ivPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer.

Comment: im currently trying to implement it, im confused by the _ID
Its giving me errors and not too sure what its actually for. Thanks

Comment: its the package ´android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts´

Comment: Should i be doing this in the Adapter? apologies i am very new to android

Comment: Do like this: save the 'contact_id' in the ContactBean class and implement the image retreival in the getview() of adapter class.

Comment: its compiling, just sorting out a few errors. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You try to get the contact id of the contact(phonenumber) and use Bitmapfactory to decode the image as shown in below working code.

```
InputStream inputStream=null;
String[] projection = new String[]{Contacts._ID};
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phnumber));
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection,
    null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    long contactId=c.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID);

    inputStream = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(activity.getContentResolver(),
                            ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, cntID));
    c.close();

}
```

use the inputstream to get bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
 holder.ivPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: ? the code worked few days ago and now its not working?.. what's the reason to accept then and again reject the answer now.

Comment: This solution worked, thanks for that. Only thing I have to change is long contactId=c.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID) to long contactId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID))