# Android get contact photo display picture if you have phone number

Tags: android, contacts, photos

I have all contact log i want to get contact image attached to the phone number and if no contact image then unknow image.

How can I do it? I have tried many method but nothing is working with me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762037/android-retrieve-contact-photo-and-display

Answer (score 0):

This is the method in official documentation to retrieve contact image.

```
 public InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) {
 Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
 Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
      new String[] {Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
 if (cursor == null) {
     return null;
 }
 try {
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
         if (data != null) {
             return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
         }
     }
 } finally {
     cursor.close();
 }
 return null;
}
```

Have a visit on this link [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html)