# Unable to display name and photo from Contacts in android

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to display a list of names and photos from contact from my android device, so I was trying to use SimpleCursorAdapter to display. I was able to display the name and phone to the listview, however, I am not able to display the photo to the imageview, is there a way to display a list of images without the use of custom adapter with the following code below ? Since I'm new to android I would love to hear from you!

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        resolver = this.getContentResolver();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);

        // Read Contacts
        Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null,
                null);

        // Attached with cursor with Adapter
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_item, c,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                new int[] { R.id.lblName });

        //for using the imageView
        mAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                                   @Override
                                   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                                       if (view.getId() == R.id.mephoto) {
                                           ImageView IV = (ImageView) view;
//I was thinking about displaying the photos from the contacts
                                           return true;
                                       }
                                       return false;
                                   }
                               }
        );
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762037/android-retrieve-contact-photo-and-display

Comment: It looks like a duplicate, however, my problem is I'm trying to set the photo images within setViewBinder without the use of custom adapters as much as possible.